# How to enable JSON support in Visual Studio (ASP.NET)?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

How do I enable Visual Studio to recognize and manipulate JSON data in the code-behind files? (In other words, resolve `json does not exist in the current context` error). I'd like to be able to:

- Retrieve JSON data from AJAX calls forwarded from the client side
- Interpret, change, or create JSON objects with C#
- Send a valid JSON response back to the client side and read it with Javascript
- Be able to do all of the above irrespective of the runtime environment (i.e. I can't always assure that I will have a third party package installed in Visual Studio)

I've seen many answers, but most suggest to either (1) install a json package or (2) play with `using` directives. I've tried many variations of the latter with no luck.

What is the proper way to include JSON support in Visual Studio?
How does one properly **retrieve** (e.g. from a POST AJAX call), **manipulate** (e.g. change), and **send back** (i.e. respond to the client) JSON data in C#? Very basic, primitive examples would help!

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net Web Form has [WebMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx). You can call those static method from client-side using Ajax.

### ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoWebApplication.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <button type="button" onclick="postData();">Post Data</button>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function postData() {
                var user = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx/postjson") %>',
                    data: "{user:" + JSON.stringify(user) + "}",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Code Behind

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace DemoWebApplication
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string PostJson(User user)
        {
            user.FirstName += "Test";
            user.LastName += "Test";
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user);
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> What is the proper way to include JSON support in Visual Studio?

Visual Studio is nothing to do with sending and receiving JSON. If you want a proper way, you might want to consider using ASP.Net Web API.